# How can I run Puppet 6 on-demand against multiple remote Linux nodes?

Tags: puppet, mcollective

On Puppet 3, I used to use `sudo mco puppet runonce -I /hostname-pattern-1/ -I /hostname-pattern-2/` to run Puppet agents on-demand against any node matching one of the hostname patterns.

As of Puppet 5.5.4, MCollective is deprecated, so I can no longer use the `mco` command.

With Puppet 6, how can I do what I used to be able to do with the `mco` command?

My server and all my nodes are running Ubuntu 20 (Linux). I'm specifically using Puppet 6.19.1 and Puppet Server 6.14.1.

I know `puppet agent -t` can be used to run Puppet on-demand, but that has to be done locally on each node, so how can I apply that command (or something equivalent) from the Puppet server to any node matching a pattern?

I know I could hardcode a bunch of hostnames in a Bash script and use SSH to remotely execute the command, but hardcoding hostnames is not as convenient as specifying hostname patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [choria](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/choria/choria/readme)?

[Puppet Bolt](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/bolt.html) might be another alternative, you could [write a task](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_tasks.html) to do something more complex, or just run [ad-hoc commands](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/running_bolt_commands.html)

e.g.

```
bolt command run 'puppet agent -t' --targets servers
```

You [connect bolt to your puppetdb](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/bolt_connect_puppetdb.html) so you won't have to create and update a static inventory